# how to count rows in table that has specific property in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
table1
--------------
| sn | class |
--------------

table2
----------------
| id | student |
----------------
```

all are `int` as `sn` is table1 is linked to student in table2
`sn`, `id` are auto increasing. when inserting data to table2 student column is same as `sn` in table 1

now I want to select `student` in table2 but only those whose `class` in table1 is "3"
my syntax is thus;

```
$count = mysql_query(SELECT student from table2 whose class in table1 =3)
```

so that i can count them by saying

```
$quantity = mysql_num_rows($count)
```

now my problem is if sql also have this whose keyword, or how do i go about this.

```
$count = mysql_query(SELECT student from table2 whose class in table1 =3)
```

Comment: You can do a join for that, but first let me note that your question is not readable. You better edit and rewrite it in a more compressible way.

Comment: Is ther any class column in table1

Comment: You dont expect my question to answer itself, if I ask, it is because I dont knw. So you try figure it out(translate from English to PHP) like someone already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join those two tables and limit your result to those which have table1.class = 3

```
SELECT
    student
FROM
    table2 a
    JOIN table1 b ON (a.student = b.sn)
WHERE b.class = 3
```

If you want a count you could also do it through SQL by using aggregate function

```
SELECT
    COUNT(student)
FROM
    table2 a
    JOIN table1 b ON (a.student = b.sn)
WHERE b.class = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables in order to filter the results properly.

(1) This will give you the number of students for class 3.

```
$count = mysql_query(
  'SELECT COUNT(t2.student) 
   FROM table2 t2 
   INNER JOIN table1 t1
     ON t1.sn = t2.student
     AND t1.class = 3'
);
```

(2) This will give you all classes and the number of students for each.

```
$count = mysql_query(
  'SELECT t1.class, COUNT(t2.student) 
   FROM table2 t2 
   INNER JOIN table1 t1
     ON t1.sn = t2.student
   GROUP BY t1.class
   ORDER BY t1.class'
);
```

(3) This will give you all classes and the students list.

```
$list = mysql_query(
  'SELECT t1.class, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.student SEPARATOR ',') 
   FROM table2 t2 
   INNER JOIN table1 t1
     ON t1.sn = t2.student
   GROUP BY t1.class
   ORDER BY t1.class'
);
```

Comment: Missing a quote in your 2nd and 3rd example.